# Sort Vector with custom sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

This works for cmp function having A.num>B.num but for lesser than it outputs zeros for all the values, idk why thanks. i'd like to know if im doing something wrong when im calling the function?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    int num;
}Node;
```

this gives an error when A.num

```
bool cmpNode(Node A,Node B){
    return A.num<=B.num;
}

int main(){

    int n;
    cin>>n;

    //std::vector<char> v;
    vector<Node> vec(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        Node temp;//    =new Node;
        cin>>temp.num;
        vec.push_back(temp);

    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),cmpNode);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout<<vec[i].num<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - it's not portable, and it's not clever.

Comment: An error? You are doing something wrong.

Comment: `<=` does not fulfil the requirements for `std::sort`.

Comment: Your comparison function is not correct.  Look up *strict weak order*.  What if `A` and `B` are equal?  Which one comes before the other?  See the problem now?  Also, there is no need for `typedef struct` in a C++ program -- just `struct` is all you need.

Comment: how exactly would i sort it in ascending order

Comment: Look again at your comparison function.  Again, what if `A` and `B` are equal?  Which one comes before the other?   You should be comparing `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: In addition to the mistake in the comparison function, look at what you're doing with `push_back`.  Your vector is already `n` elements, yet you're pushing back even more.  That is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is statement `vector<Node> vec(n)`, which initialises the vector with `n` "empty" nodes before you additionally add another `n` nodes with individual values. So if you sort ascending, and then print the first `n` nodes, it is very likely that you print the "empty" ones, i.e. the ones with value `0` (which shine up in the beginning).

So mainly you should write

```
vector<Node> vec;
```

Further, as stated by others, a comparison function used for `std::sort` must meet 
a strict weak ordering relation (cf. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)):

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
>   of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if
>   the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict
>   weak ordering relation induced by this Compare type, and false
>   otherwise.

This means, among other requirements, that...

> For all a, comp(a,a)==false

Comment: The program will still be faulty if there are duplicate items in the vector.  The change in the sort comparison function is required (in addition to the issue with the vector `push_back` call).  Running the program, including your change, under Visual C++ debug mode crashes on the `std::sort` call due to the improper comparison function.

Comment: Also, your answer is actually a function declaration, and does not create a `vector<Node>`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through each mistake:

**Issue 1:**

You are calling `push_back` on a vector that has already been sized to `n` entries.  Thus in the input loop, you're just adding more items to the end of the `vector`, thus increasing its size.

The correction should be as follows:

```
vector<Node> vec;
```

**Issue 2:**

The comparison function for `std::sort` requires a *strict-weak-order*.  In other words, your function must uniquely state, when given two items, which item comes first in the sorted order by returning `true` if the first item comes before the second item, `false` otherwise.

Your comparison function violates this,  since you return `true` if `A == B`, and `true` again if `B == A`.  So does `A` come before `B` or `B` come before `A`?

Of course, this will not work correctly and will totally throw off the sorting algorithm if you have duplicate items in the vector (this is what Visual C++ debug runtime does to check if you have a valid comparison function -- the comparison function is called twice and checks the return value for both calls).

The correction should be as follows:

```
bool cmpNode(const Node& A, const Node& B){
    return A.num < B.num;
}
```

Also note the usage of passing by reference instead of by value.

Comment: Thanks, the main problem was i had previously initialized 'n' values in the vector and while sorting i was getting 0's in ascending order....

i really need to ask what difference it would make if i pass the Node by value or reference?

Comment: If you pass by value, you are creating temporary copies of `Node`.  If `Node` is an expensive object to copy, then you're potentially slowing your program down.  Also, you had two "main" problems.  The first is the vector, but the second, which I pointed out in the answer, is not only another main problem, it would have been very hard to detect if you were not aware of it.  If your vector contained duplicates, then your program would have exhibit undefined behavior on the sort.